# Webos Port 9922 is not avaiable

Tags: webos, smart-tv

After installing newer version of Developer Mode on my LG TV, most of the time when I open the Developer Mode, port 9922 is not open and I can't deploy my application on device. I kept getting this error and there is no way to avoid it:

```
Error: Please check the device IP address or port.
```

Does anyone encounter the same problem here?!

Comment: I am having the same issue, have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I posted a thread about it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191761/lg-webos-could-not-connect-to-the-device-please-check-the-device-connection