# LG WEBOS : Could not connect to the device, please check the device connection

Tags: command-line-interface, webos, lg, smart-tv

I've followed everything here step by step :  [App Testing on webOS TV](http://developer.lge.com/webOSTV/develop/web-app/app-test/#preparingAccount)

But I still can't seem to connect using either the webOS CLI or the webOS IDE.

I get the following error:

Via the IDE : 
 **Could not connect to the device "name", please check the device connection.**

Via webOs CLI : 
**ares-install ERR! ares-install: Error: Please check the device IP address or port.**

---

I see the device listed : ares-setup-device --list

- emulator  developer@127.0.0.1:6622     ssh         tv lgtv_
- prisoner@10.188.20.165:9922            ssh         tv

I am able to ping the device IP through command line.

---

Installing and running an app via webOS CLI on the emulator works fine, it just won't work when it comes to the actual device.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you've completed the key exchange steps before trying to install. You'll need to turn "Key Server" on in the device "Developer Mode" app as well as "Dev Mode Status".

After adding the device with `ares-setup-device` you want to run

```
  ares-novacom --device YOUR_DEVICE_NAME --getkey
```

and enter the passphrase shown on the device.

You should then be able to use `ares-install`.

Source: http://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/app-test/

Answer (score 5):

My issue was solved when I changed the device name from Home Office to home. I think a space in the device name was causing the error.

Comment: How could you change the name ? am using windows . The only command i know to modify is "ares-setup-device". But this lets change everything but not device name

Comment: If you want to use spaces in names, wrap them into double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading a firmware - IDE stopped connecting to real TV "Could not connect to the device "name", please check the device connection."
I tried to reinstall the Developer Mode application - after deleting the app a new installation caused an error (something like "temporary error, try again later"). The reboot didn't solve the problem.
I tried to connect to the TV via PuTTY, but connection was always refused (before this problem occured connection was successful).
**So, I did a factory reset of the TV, then installation of the Developer Mode app was successful, and the whole problem was gone - now IDE successfully connects to the TV.**
I think, it was an internal problem in the TV - for example, SSH-server didn't work properly.

Comment: A factory reset should never be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this LG Developer help](https://www.lgwebos.com/topic/1958-error-ares-install-please-check-the-device-ip-address-or-port/) it says that you should change your port to 22

Comment: But changing port number doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved when I disabled Hyper-V

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
```

and ran virtualbox machine manually

Comment: Am using windows , runnning creating an app and running it on emulator via CLI first time . Below commands i used to generate , package and install :
`SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\fDrive\Softwares\LGWebOS_SDK\ares-webos-cli\ares-cli\bin`
`ares-generate -t basic -p "{'id':'com.domain.app', 'version':'1.0.0', 'title':'First App'}" samples/projects/app`
`ares-package .`
`ares-install  com.domain.app_1.0.0_all.ipk -d emulator -v `

install is failing with same error as mentioned here . Do i need to run server or virtualbox seperately ? Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by turning on Key Server on TV(devMode app) adding SSH key on Target Device

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had added two TVs and I failed in the command line to pass the device name using the `-d` flag. This made the tool connect to the wrong TV at the wrong IP.

Correct example:

```
ares-install my-app.ipk -d 'name-of-tv'
```